# Hyper-V - Copy text inside VM & paste text to workstation (outside of Hyper-V) text editor?

Tags: hyper-v

I just migrated from VMWare to Hyper-V because of Docker.

Then I noticed I cannot copy the text inside Hyper-V VM & paste this text to workstation text editor (outside of Hyper-V VM)?

So, I did the google search & most answer I found are, the other way around (workstation to hyper-v) but not this way I mentioned above.

So, how does this work? Suggested Google links?

[My Workstation]

```
Windows 10 Pro for Workstations, Version (??, 02/12/2020 Windows Update)
Hyper-V Manager Version 10.0.18362.1
```

[Hyper-V VM #1] - Doesnt Work

```
Windows 7
```

[Hyper-V VM #2] - Works

```
Windows 10, Version (02/2020 Windows Update)
```

[image]

Comment: Please indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using.  You should edit your question to include this information.  Understanding what version you are using might help better answer your question.  You never really addressed if you had enabled Enhanced Mode.  Please note we know nothing about VM1 and VM2.  **If one works and the other does not, you need to identify what is different about them, and provide us that information.** We can't determine the reason one works and the other doesn't without understanding how they are different.

Comment: Check the status of the [Hyper-V Integration Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/manage-hyper-v-integration-services).

Comment: Windows 7 as guest does not support this enhanced functions. At least not the same way as Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

#### I cannot copy the text inside Hyper-V VM & paste this text to workstation text editor

Do you have enhanced mode enabled?

Before you connect, click on "Show Options":

> [image]
>
> Enhanced Mode supports fully integrated, bidirectional (host to guest,
> guest to host) clipboard. It is enabled by default:
>
> [image]

Source [Shared clipboard between Hyper-V VM and Win 10 host - Windows 10 Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/141251-shared-clipboard-between-hyper-v-vm-win-10-host.html)

Comment: If you're referring to Enhanced Session.   That icon is greyed out.

Comment: I added screen snapshot above in original post (this comment doesn't allow image posting)

Comment: @ScottFletcher See updated answer.

Comment: That pop up doesn't show up for this VM image, so not sure how to get there.  2 other VM disk images does show this but not this one.

Comment: @ScottFletcher {shrug} perhaps you should update the question to include the OS and version of both the host and the VMs where it works and the VM where it doesn't.

Comment: I updated the post