# Copy and paste text from windows to another OS in hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

My host OS is windows 10 and I create a Linux VM  in Hyper-V. I'd like to copy some text in my host windows 10 and paste it into a text editor in my guest OS - Linux.

I already checked all **Enhanced Session/options available in Hyper-V Settings** but I don't know why it still doesn't work

This thread doesn't resolve my question
[Hyper-V - Copy text inside VM & paste text to workstation (outside of Hyper-V) text editor?](https://superuser.com/questions/1525434/hyper-v-copy-text-inside-vm-paste-text-to-workstation-outside-of-hyper-v-t)

I don't even see **Edit Session Settings** in my HV Manager
[edit session settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjsSo.png)

And can't see how I connect as a some specific user
[show options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UENlK.png)

Comment: Check the virtual machine Settings. Under Management, are all Integration Services enabled?

Comment: All of them are enabled

Comment: Try in the VM to install `yum install hyperv-daemons`.

Comment: Yes, then what ?

Comment: If they have been installed, now see [this article](https://techlabs.blog/categories/debian-linux/install-linux-integration-services-and-hyper-v-daemons-on-debian).

Comment: Also make sure the guest you have support integration services.  My guest does not appear to and does not support copying. If you need data from Host to guest, try moving it in a file.

Answer (score -1):

The copy-and-paste functions of the Clipboard can be used to move files to and from virtual computers while using Enhanced Session Mode. However, if the Do not allow drive redirection policy option is activated, copying and pasting files through the Clipboard is blocked.